# is it necessary to keep older versions of Android SDK installed with Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android

In the Android DSK Manager under "Installed Packages", I see things like:

```
SDK Platform Android 3.2
SDK Platform Android 3.1
SDK Platform Android 3.0
SDK Platform Android 2.3
SDK Platform Android 2.2
SDK Platform Android 2.1
SDK Platform Android 1.6
SDK Platform Android 1.5
```

Is it necessary to keep the older SDKs, if I am programming with the latest SDK?

Answer (score 4):

No. You dont need older packages if you are sure about developing with latest packages.

Comment: And so, if I delete them, I can always re-install through the SDK Manager correct?  The only reason I ask, is because I removed one of the old ones and no longer see it in the list of available SDKs.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. You can always re-install them whenever you need it via SDK Manager

Comment: My Suggestion is Don't delete any older version SDK. It wont cost much disk space :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to keep those packages which your application is not using. Generally you should keep those versions installed which your application is going to use. Like your application may use version from 8 to 10. So no need to keep lower than 8. So that depends on your application which version it will use.

Comment: If I build with version 8 (to have the external storage option), and if I have <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" /> in my manifest (to allow old devices to use it)... should I keep all installed packages?

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but I would like to share my experience.

**Yes**, if you are using **Instant Run** and using SDK 21 or higher then you should keep SDK Platforms.

For Example, if have deleted the SDK Platform 22 and testing on Android 5.1 device or emulator then Android Studio will ask you to install SDK Platform if you want to use instant run else **instant run will not work.**